# indexedDB highest keypath

Tags: javascript, ember.js, indexeddb

I have a database inside indexedDB filled using an Emberjs adapter. I have set the keypath like this:

`this.addModel(App.Device, { keyPath: 'key' });`

And my key is autoincremented when I parse my data the first time I got them like this:

```
data = data.map(function( item, idx ) {
    item.key = idx;
    return item;
});
```

After all of the data are store inside indexedDB, I want to add some more data, but I need to get to continue to set a key value inside my data.

How can I get the highest key (in my case it's a unique number (like an id)), so I can increment the one the key in my current data to add to my database?

Here is the sample of my code that I want to use to add more data:

```
var request = indexedDB.open( 'products' );
request.onsuccess = function( e ) {
    console.log('Success!');
    that.setProperties({ db: e.target.result });
    var db = e.target.result;
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob_);
    var img64;
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        base64data = reader.result;
        var dataImage = {
            key: 42,
            url: url_,
            base64: base64data
        }
        that.storage.saveProduct( db, dataImage );
    }
};

request.onerror = function( e ) {
    console.log('Error!');
    console.dir( e );
};
```

[edit] I forgot to put the saveProduct fct:

```
this.saveProduct = function( db, data ) {
    var transaction = db.transaction( ["App.Device"], "readwrite" );
    var store = transaction.objectStore( "App.Device" );

    var request = store.add( data );

    request.onerror = function( e ) {
        console.log("Error",e.target.error.name);
        //some type of error handler
    };

    request.onsuccess = function( e ) {
        console.log("Device saved in db");
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`objectStore.openKeyCursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/openKeyCursor) with the direction "prev":

```js
const openCursorRequest = store.openKeyCursor(null, 'prev')
openCursorRequest.onsuccess = () => {
  const cursor = openCursorRequest.result
  const maxKey = cursor && cursor.key
  // use maxKey...
}
```

Using [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
const getMaxKey = (db, storeName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readonly')
  const store = tx.objectStore(storeName)
  const openCursorRequest = store.openKeyCursor(null, 'prev')
  openCursorRequest.onsuccess = () => {
    const cursor = openCursorRequest.result
    resolve(cursor && cursor.key)
  }
  openCursorRequest.onerror = () => {
    reject(openCursorRequest.error)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an IDB pattern for the last entry:

1. Bind your cursor value to the first ID entry. (`"0"` should do it since keys are lexicographically ordered.) (Original answer linked to question https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812410/317937 which has now been removed)
2. Use a reverse cursor ("`prev`" or "`prevunique`" direction depending on your needs)
3. Your next entry will be the last entry (`skip()` or `continue()` either should work)

Comment: How do you "Bind your cursor value to the first ID entry"?