# How to get the info of last record in an indexeddb ObjectStore?

Tags: indexeddb

How to get the info of last record in an indexeddb ObjectStore? 
Any direction approach to get it?

Want to read the index of last record in a specific ObjectStore.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, take a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909932/indexeddb-retrieve-item-with-max-value/21911709#21911709

Comment: Sorry for not able to vote your answer up. reputation not enough :(

Comment: We'll help you out with that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765265/indexeddb-highest-keypath/23767434#23767434